# htaccess rewrite replace .php with /

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've recently started a new site, and for the sake of keeping links clean I want to rewrite urls.
I need to rewrite the links like this :
www.domain.com/post.php?post=15 
↓
www.domain.com/post/15
and
www.domain.com/user.php?user=USERNAME
↓
www.domain.com/user/USERNAME

I used to change links from www.domain.com/page.php?page=PAGE to www.domain.com/PAGE , but this time I need both "post" and "user" to work fine, and I can't quite figure it out.
Can someone please help me out with a tip on how to do this?
Thank you in advance
Chris

Solved with Jon Lin's help. His answer works great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the "/" in your regex in order for it to work. But if your links are relative, browsers will try to resolve them like `http://domain.com/page/some.css` instead of `http://domain.com/some.css`. You need to add this to the top of all your pages:

```
<base href="/">
```

Or whatever the base of all your relative links should be. And your rules should look like this:

```
RewriteRule ^post/([^/]*)$ /post.php?p=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^user/([^/]*)$ /user.php?p=$1 [L]
```

And this should rewrite urls like `http://www.domain.com/post/15` and `http://www.domain.com/user/USERNAME`

Comment: That worked great. The links are exactly how I wanted them now. Didn't know about the " <base href='/'> " . Thank you so much for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking into some PHP Frameworks. They'll help you do this as well as helping you keep your code cleaner and more manageable

Comment: Hey. I'm trying to do it with mod_rewrite, the .htaccess rewriter, but i'm a complete rookie at url rewriting